# Development environment on my machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am really new in ASP.NET and C# so please be patient.

I develop an application. I have full access to the production database.

Since now I used only my tables, but now I need to use a table where are production data.

I've created a new database and added a new connection string to `Web.config` file.

So the production connection string names are:

```
Prod: myconnectiond
Dev:  devconnection
```

My goal is to use the devconnection while I develop.

I've put it this into my database connect method:

```
if (Environment.MachineName.ToLower() == "mymachine" && connectionName == "myconnection") {
    connectionName = "devconnection";
}
```

Is it a good practice, or does exists better?

Comment: How do you release software to production?

Comment: Does it work for you? Then great.

Comment: @spender This is why I am asking because I am not know. I am a newbie at my company and now I am learning C# and ASP.NET just right now. And the guy who do that not here right now, but I'd like to work right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the #IF preprocessor in your code, and basically it would work like this.

```cs
string ConnectionName = string.Empty;
#if DEBUG
ConnectionName = "devconnection";
#elif RELEASE
ConnectionName = "myconnectiond";
#endif
```

What this will do is when you have your build configuration set to Debug (or development) it will compile your code as if it was this:

```cs
string ConnectionName = string.Empty;
ConnectionName = "devconnection";
```

And when you have it set to Release it will compile it like this:

```cs
string ConnectionName = string.Empty;
ConnectionName = "myconnectiond";
```

All without you having to change anything other than the build configuration.

You can find more info here: [#if (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

Comment: This is the good solution. The problem is that, the web config is only for build, not while developing.

Answer (score 2):

In lastest versions of Visual Studio, it is possible to change your web.config configurations based on the build configuration.

When creating a web.config, you will see two files:

- **Web.Debug.Config**
- **Web.Release.Config**

Change the connection string in debug config file to point development database and release config fle to point production database.

Comment: What is not clear for me, what happens, if I am leaving it on Debug and then push to GIT, and PM deploy it? Couldn't it accidentally use the dev DB in this case?

Comment: In your case it will use Production db when PM Deploys it.